# Isolation -Phantom read in REPEATABLE READ

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

**Does this PARTICULAR case fall into the non-repeatable read category or as a phantom read**?
I don't think this QUESTION is DUPLICATED because I have not seen this particular case anywhere.

```
 begin;            
                                   begin;
                                   select * from bancos where id = 2;
delete from bancos where id = 2;  
                                    select * from bancos where id = 2; //same data, expected

commit;
                                select * from bancos where id = 2; //here he should have hidden it because it allows for phantom reads
                                commit;
                                select * from bancos where id = 2; // Eliminated, now yes
```

**I'm using repeatable read**, that's why I thought the DELETE would be considered phantom read, because repeatable read in MySQL allows phantom read, therefore, I think that in the penultimate SELECT of console 2 (the one on the right) **the record should not come out** (even without applying the commit) because it's a phantom read and **REPEATABLE READ allows phantom read**

In a UPDATE I understand
[image]

but then how do you explain the above case with a delete? **A DELETE is then considered a non-repeatable read so it appears as long as you don't commit?**

Answer (score 3):

Isolation levels define *minimum* requirements to consistency, not a maximum.

So just because repeatable read is *allowed* to produce phantom reads, doesn't mean it *has* to. Nobody actually wants phantom reads. You just accept them in certain isolation levels because it allows other transactions to finish faster. But if the database has a way to prevent them (even at the cost of making other transactions wait), it is allowed to do that in any isolation level.

MySQL uses a snapshot technique, which reduces the number of phantom reads you experience, including the situation in your case where you read exactly the same rows again (and MySQL can show you the saved version).

If you want to get some phantom reads though, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178461) where an update to a row inserted in another session generates a phantom row. If you do the same with serializable isolation, the insert in the other transaction will have to wait - but as required by that isolation level, does not produce a phantom row.